# Function to copy the whole line if no region is selected

Tags: copy-paste

I want to bind this function to `M-w`, so that it copies the region if one is selected, otherwise it copies the whole line silently, without having any other side-effects like moving the cursor to some other places.

I saw some examples, but they all do some additional stuff that I don't like, like moving the cursor to the next line.

I'm not an expert in Elisp, but some functions I saw might be buggy, because their bodies contain `"\n"`, to refer to "newline", which is obviously wrong, because not all systems use this convention.

Comment: Emacs represents newlines as `"\n"` internally, no matter how the newline is encoded when it's stored in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid side effects like moving the point (that is, the cursor), wrap your movement commands in `save-excursion`. Prior Emacs 25 this also saved the mark (the other end of the selected region).  Now to save the mark as well use `save-mark-and-excursion`.

First we need a function to select the whole line:

```
(defun mark-whole-line ()
  (beginning-of-line)
  (set-mark-command nil)
  (end-of-line))
```

This function moves the point and the mark.

Now we need to know if the region is active. The function `region-active-p` does this. Now just check the state of the region and use an if/then to either call the normal function `M-w` is bound to or save the state, use the above function to mark the whole line and then copy it:

```
(defun kill-ring-save-whole-line-or-region ()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (call-interactively #'kill-ring-save) ;; then
    (save-mark-and-excursion ;; else
      (mark-whole-line)
      (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
      (pop-mark)
      )))
```

Finally to bind it to a key: `(define-key global-map (kbd "M-w") #'kill-ring-save-whole-line-or-region)`

Comment: I get the following error: 

**Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Key sequence M - w starts with non-prefix key M")** 

But when I use the following line it works properly: 

**(global-set-key (kbd "M-w") 'kill-ring-save-whole-line-or-region)**

Comment: @BiteBytes That's the part I typed without testing it. Fixed now.

Comment: FWIW, I have a similar command in [`misc-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/misc-cmds.el). Putting it here just for info: (defun mark-line (&optional arg)
  "Put mark at end of line, point at beginning.
A numeric prefix arg means move forward (backward if negative) that
many lines, thus marking a line other than the one point was
originally in."
  (interactive "P")
  (setq arg  (if arg (prefix-numeric-value arg) 0))
  (let ((inhibit-field-motion  t))
    (forward-line arg)
    (push-mark nil t t)
    (goto-char (line-end-position))))

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`whole-line-or-region`](https://github.com/purcell/whole-line-or-region) package.  With `whole-line-or-region-local-mode` activated, things like `C-w` and `M-w` Do The Right Thing on the current line when then is no active region.